# How to fixed it, 'Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute' when i use BTrace?

Tags: jar, agent, btrace

When I use BTrace, I got this problem. But I don't know how to fix it. The Linux command is:

```
btrace 16625 LiveServiceMethods.class
```

The problem is:

> Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute.

Comment: Looks like the BTrace installation is corrupted.
What is the output of 'btrace --version' ? Also which JDK is running your target application?

Comment: BTrace version : 1.3.8.1, JDK version: 1.7.0_60(64bit)

Comment: the debug log is 'DEBUG: server not yet available; retrying ...', how to set?

Comment: netty server port is 7784 and i use this command like 'btrace -v -p 7784 30040 LiveServiceMethods.class '

Comment: Are you trying to run the BTrace on the same port as netty? You really should not.

Comment: the port is 2020 or the application port. i don't know. it couldn't connect to the server, the problem is 'DEBUG: server not yet available; retrying ..' Can you help me? it confuse me this days.